# Should C enum return function end by semicolon

Tags: c, enums, jetbrains-ide

I ask this question because of release of new JetBrains product CLion.
I started testing new C/C++ ide and when I typed simple function that return enum, Clion (JetBrains) put automatically the semicolon ";" at the end of closing brackets.

```
 enum Error someCode(void)
 {
    //some code
 }; //<- semicolon at end
```

but after non enum function

```
void nonEnumFunct(void)
{
   //some code
} //<- without semicolon
```

I never consider that before (because I have a lot of respect to JetBrains products :) butI think CLion misunderstood that the  someCode is function that returns enum but not enum. Because function should not have ";" at the end even if it return enum structure.

My question is: if it is good practise to declare function as returning enum or shoud I always declare enum as:

```
typedef enum some_enum {} AnEnum;
```

and then use it as returning type in function declaration.

Comment: Clion or whatever is wrong. You don't need a `;` at the end of a function definition.

Comment: My best bet is that as you start typing the keyword `enum`, the IDE thinks you want to *declare* an `enum`.  Indeed, `enum` declarations need to be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: To verify my hypothesis: do you observe the same effect with the keyword `struct`?

Comment: Considering CLion is at an EAP stage, such bugs are common. They said it's to be considered a pre-beta phase.

Comment: yes when I typed struct driver * getTheDriver(void){ ...
    
it put me a " }; " at the end

Comment: @Rosme so that is the case that I test it :)

Comment: is the enum 'Error' defined before this point in the code?  Is the prototype for the function defined after the enum definition and before the actual function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a question of good or bad practice.

Semicolons are simply *not* allowed in C after a function definition.

Regarding the question of whether you should typedef or not enum types, there is no right answer, it's a matter of taste. I personally prefer not to typedef enum types as I consider typedef (except in some cases) as an obfuscation.

Comment: Both `clang-3.4 -ansi` and `gcc-4.4 -ansi` accept such an extra semicolon without warning. What makes you believe that they are not allowed? Can you please cite the standard?

Comment: @pts gcc with `-pedantic` option will give you the required diagnostic: *ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function*

Comment: @pts The relevant part of the standard would be the syntax of a function definition, see C11 6.9.1. There is no semicolon in the syntax, meaning it is not allowed. (As opposed to for example the syntax for a `do while` loop in 6.8.5, which contains a semicolon at the end, meaning it is mandatory.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the IDE (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-1027). It should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

Semicolons are not needed after function definitions (not even after such ones), and they are not encouraged by any style guide I know.

Most probably this as a bug in your IDE. It tries to be smart to predict that your are declaring a variable or a type. But it's wrong.

Comment: If so, it'd be nice to fill up a bug report :-)